# Attempting to check if PFFile has data or not

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pffile

I am attempting to check if a PFFile has data before it attempts to pull the image from the background. I am attempting this because I keep getting a fatal crash if you try and open one of the objects and there is no image! My problem is that I can't get the data check to work. `PFFile != nil` does not work and you can't check if it exists with `if (recipeImageData)` because PFFile does not conform to the boolean protocol. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is the declaration of the variable:

```
var recipeImageData: PFFile = PFFile()
```

And here is the function for fetching the data:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  navItem.title = recipeObject["Name"] as? String
  recipeImageData = recipeObject["Image"] as PFFile //Fatally crashes on this line
  // Fetch the image from the background
  if (recipeImageData) {
    recipeImageData.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
      (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        self.recipeImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)?
      } else {
        println("Error: \(error.description)")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

EDIT:

I just tried this seeing that I probably am making a check in the wrong area. Here is my updated code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  navItem.title = recipeObject["Name"] as? String
  if let recipeImageData = recipeObject["Image"] as? PFFile {
    // Fetch the image in the background
    recipeImageData.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
      (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        self.recipeImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)?
      } else {
        println("Error: \(error.description)")
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried? `if(recipeObject["Image"])` before `recipeImageData = recipeObject["Image"]`

Comment: This results in a fatal crash with Parse though saying there is an unrecognized selector being sent to the class in parse though

Comment: Yeah I realized that @Klevison and the updated code shows the check where I attempt to check for it but I think my updated code might still be wrong. PFFile can't be an optional so that might be wrong

Comment: @KlevisonMatias I tired the check you suggested too but I get the same fatal error with Parse not recognizing a selector sent to it

Comment: pastebin your model (PFObject) please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This check actually works just fine, there was another issue that was causing the crash. The correct code is posted below:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  navItem.title = recipeObject["Name"] as? String
  if let recipeImageData = recipeObject["Image"] as? PFFile {
    // Fetch the image in the background
    recipeImageData.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
      (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        self.recipeImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)?
      } else {
        println("Error: \(error.description)")
      }
    })
  }
}
```